# One gamepad is seen as two by applications

Tags: usb, games

I have a single game controller connected via USB. (It's a Stadia controller.) In System Settings > Game Controllers it shows up as a single game controller. It also only appears once in System Information > USB.

But applications see it in duplicate. Chrome sees it as two controllers when I go to https://luser.github.io/gamepadtest/. Steam Link sees it as two controllers. In the menu one press of up/down causes two steps. In games I get to control two characters. It's not great.

At some point I installed the [SDL2 Gamepad Tool](https://generalarcade.com/gamepadtool/) so maybe that's the culprit? I've asked it to reset the `SDL_GAMECONTROLLERCONFIG` environment variable, and from Terminal I can confirm it's not set. Is there anything else I could check?

Comment: In Chrome both appear as "Stadia Controller". In Steam link they are "Stadia Controller" and "Google Stadia Controller". In Steam they are "Generic Gamepad: Google Stadia Controller" and "Apple Controller". I think one of them comes from SDL. But how do I stop that.

Comment: Does Stadia have Mac drivers?

Comment: I think Stadia controller support was added in macOS 13. So when I used it earlier, I needed the SDL2 Gamepad Tool to get it working. But after updating to macOS 13 I ended up with the duplication.